# How to update all objects if I change one of them

Tags: adobe-indesign

I use InDesign to print labels with it. The manufacturer of the labels offers templates for InDesign with the dimensions already drawn in.

Currently I proceed as follows:

1. I create the label
2. group all objects
3. copy it to the other positions

When I make a change, I have to delete all objects (except one). Ungroup there, make the change and do step 1-3 as before.

Is there a possibility to create a group and all copy are a kind of reference that automatically update as soon as I adjust the reference?

Comment: yes you can do this fully automatic with the XML processing of indesign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I would personally do as @Westside suggests. It's the simplest and easiest method. But I'll add this answer for completeness.)*

You could use the **Content Collector Tool**.

[image]

- Select the *Content Collector Tool*.
- Make sure it's in *Content Collector Tool* mode.
- Click the object or group you want to clone.
- Switch to *Content Placer Tool* mode.
- Make sure *Create link* is ticked.
- Make sure *Place multiple and keep in conveyor* is selected.
- Place clones of the object by clicking in the document.

Now the clones are linked to the original object. If you change something in the original object the clones will get the yellow *Modified* warning in the Links panel and you can *Update* them to apply the changes.

Comment: The Content Collector Tool is one of things I sometimes see mentioned, but have never actually used – this is an excellent illustration of a perfect use case for it. I think this is much easier and cleaner than Westside’s solution: it requires only one file and thus keeps everything neatly compartmentalised. I will see if I can remember to think of this next time I need to do something similar!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, yeah it seems nice. You can even link across documents. I tried using it a bit, but it's a bit quirky. Check out the link's *Link Options* to control which attributes get updated! It needs some planning ahead. Like if for example you make some icon you want to use many places, you should remember to group it with some invisible rectangle or paste the graphics into a rectangle. That makes it easier to add more shapes and handle rotating and scaling. You can't easily fix it later. (Hope it makes sense ... hard to explain in few words.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution! That's exactly what I was looking for!
I am currently in the process of designing new honey  labels and will be done in minutes. Thanks for that! 

Comment: @DominicJonas, good to hear! I'll just repeat though, that I I wouldn't personally do it like this. I would do as Westside suggests and make two documents. One for a single label and one for the sheet. All print providers *I* work with just want a PDF containing a single label in the wanted dimensions and then they'll distribute it on whatever sheet they use. It might change and perhaps at some time you'll want the labels on a roll instead of a sheet. So having a base document of a single label is best practice imo. Also *much* easier to design when it comes to margins, centering etc.

Comment: Thanks again for the hint. I'll keep it in mind should I have higher requirements in the future. I use the labels from Herma, which already have a ready-made template for InDesign. https://www.herma.co.uk/office-home/product/adhesive-labels-a4-movables-10304/ (see download section below). If I ever switch to a different system or print different labels, I'll definitely come back to **Westside's** suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Try this process instead:

1. Create an InDesign document that is just one label
2. Save the single label InDesign file for future edits
3. Export the single label as a PDF
4. Place the PDF in your template document and then duplicate it across the layout as required

Now, if changes are required, just update the single label, re-export the PDF (with the same file name) and update all of the instances of the label in the layout file.

Comment: Why export to PDF in the first place? Why not just place the single-label InDesign file directly?

Comment: That would work too. In terms of a workflow, I like to have the intermediary file (pdf in this case) as a fixed asset, separate from the working document.  Personal preference I suppose, but feels like best practice to me.